# ReferenceError in elasticsearch with javascript

Tags: elasticsearch

I am experimenting with a node application for Elasticsearch. My code:

```
var esRequest = "  {\n" +
            "      \"title\": {\n" +
            "        \"value\": \"java\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }";


let body = {
  size: 20,
  from: 0,
  query
}
body.query.match = JSON.parse(esRequest)
esClient.search({index:"myindex",body:body});
```

I get error as:

> ReferenceError: query is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Made this change, and it worked:

```
let body = {
  size: 20,
  from: 0,
  query: {}
}
body.query.match = JSON.parse(esRequest)
```